# sql update trigger to grab updated data and also select other row data

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to find a way so that when a specific column gets updated on a table that an update trigger (or maybe something else) can then select the stop number column from the same row that the datetime was update on. I want to capture the stop number and the column data before/after the update into another table. I do ok with SQL but I'm no expert so I just can't think of how to accomplish this.

Is it possible?

Comment: please explain with some sample data and explain expected result

Comment: Tip: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Also, don't whatever you do, start any long running processes inside a trigger. Get in, get out. Handle the data you capture outside the trigger with a separate, independent, process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. Have a read through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx). Basically there are two virtual tables, deleted and inserted, that you can query in a trigger. Deleted contains the row that is being deleted, and inserted (you guessed it) the row being inserted.

"How does that help? I'm doing an update." Indeed but an update is effectively a delete followed by an insert, so in an after update trigger you can get at the old value in deleted.

Comment: So (without looking) are you saying that by updating only 1 column from 1 row in an update statement that the inserted and deleted tables have the entire row?

Comment: Yes. The deleted table will hold the entirety of the old row and the inserted, the new. You'll see the same column names appear in intellisense.

Comment: I thought that they housed only the changes. Well then this solves my problem!